# Data Dictionary or ORM?

Tags: database, frameworks

I am in the processes of replacing the framework for a fairly complex business web application.  Our application runs on a LAMP platform and the new framework will be an extension of [CodeIgniter.](http://www.codeigniter.com)  In my research for framework design I decided to look into ORM, I have never done ORM before and I wanted to know if it would be valuable for our application.  Then I stumbled on a very interesting blog post entitled ["Why I Do Not Use ORM."](http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2008/06/why-i-do-not-use-orm.html)  This blog seemed to confirm many of my worries about using ORM and it also presented a solution similar to what I was already planning.

By "data dictionary" I plan to use this definition from ["The Database Programmer"](http://database-programmer.blogspot.com) blog:

> The term "data dictionary" is used by many, including myself, to denote a separate set of tables that describes the application tables. The Data Dictionary contains such information as column names, types, and sizes, but also descriptive information such as titles, captions, primary keys, foreign keys, and hints to the user interface about how to display the field.

So in choosing a "data dictionary" over ORM I may be exhibiting confirmation bias, regardless here are my reasons for being weary of ORM:

1. I have never used ORM before, I don't know much about it.
2. This framework needs to be built rather quickly, my boss has little time and I need to produce a working application that will allow for a smooth upgrade to a more modern framework.
3. My boss already thinks that I am over engineering this framework (trust me, I am no where close to that) and is paranoid about the framework preventing us from being able to do things that we need to, and creating bugs that we can't solve in the required amount of time.  So far I have done a poor job of convincing him that change is good, I am not a very effective salesman and while the other developers can help me the boss still needs a lot of assurance.
4. Our old framework is procedural, our code is PHP, and our developers know SQL very well.  ORM would be a big change.
5. Our database has dozens of tables, many with hundreds of thousands of entries running on a fairly old server.  In the past we have been burned by code that repeated polls the database in a loop instead of doing one query to pull all of the needed data at once.  Avoiding this problem with hand coded SQL is rather straight forward.  Ensuring that this always happens where necessary with ORM is a huge unknown to me and appears to be risky.

Regardless, the solution of the data dictionary seems very promising to me as this blog post ["Using A Data Dictionary"](http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2008/06/using-data-dictionary.html) seems to provide a lot of useful features and some that are requirements of the new framework.  Here are my reasons for preferring the data dictionary solution:

1. Implementing access control rules on the table rows themselves would be invaluable.
2. Auto-generating database changes, documentation, and schema checking would also be useful.
3. One requirement of the framework is a generic data history/auditing feature that can be applied to any sub-feature within our application.  A data dictionary or an equivalent is essentially required to provide such a feature.  The history must have detailed information about the structure and data types within the database.
4. Our systems hold a wide variety of data types that would more properly addressed if they treated as formal types within the application.  For one, HTML fragments (of which we have many in our data, they are required) need to be encoded as entities in some cases, decoded as HTML in others, parsed for links and images in some cases, and always validated for correctness.  Then there are dates, measurements, currency, and various other fields that could benefit from having a clear definition in the code of how this data should be manipulated.

The data dictionary idea that I would like to implement would be series of objects in separate PHP files, and there will be plenty of OOP, however it will be used as in a manner very similar to the data dictionary concept presented in "The Database Programmer" blog.  It would be the single source definition of the complete database schema for the entire framework.

Now my question is, am I overlooking the value of ORM or is this a case where a data dictionary is the right tool for the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question would be more interesting if you were making an initial architectural decision rather than refactoring an existing application. I don't see a single assertion in your question that suggests a problem that designing in an ORM would address; but several it would create. If two major stakeholder groups (owner and other developers are more comfortable with a more conventional design, it seems to me that an ORM would be swimming upstream.

I can imagine the (possibly undeserved) approbation that would be associated with the ORM as soon as a query is slow or transaction locking problems start emerging. Not to mention the impact on the development schedule. Why create an unquantified risk factor?

Comment: It is a fairly thorough overhall.  None of the old server side code will be in the new system.  But your answer seems correct.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a framework which supports building applications using a "Data Dictionary"? If so, give it a try, it might solve your problems. If you haven't, then there are lots of good and working ORM frameworks out there which have large communities, which come with source (so you can fix bugs yourself even if the "vendor" refuses to help you).

If you want to get a quick glance at a nice web based ORM framework, I suggest [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) or [TurboGears](http://turbogears.org/). They are based on Python which will be a nice change after using PHP. I usually prefer TurboGears but Django seems to be more smooth at the moment. Both are easy to set up and you should be able to build a prototype in a day or two. That will give you an idea of the odds.

PS: I also don't think ORM tools are TEH SOLUT10N. I use Hibernate or SQL Alchemy when it makes sense but I often roll my own simple mappers.

Comment: Python is definitely not an option.  There's no way I could sell that to my boss, all of our developers do LAMP (Linux Apache MySQL and PHP).  He'd have to invest in retraining all of us.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have made a very good analysis for you situation. You know why you choose the Data Dictionary approach. So go for it.

Later on you might reconsider. If so, then there should be not a problem to use the Data Dictionary and a ORM for new developments in parallel. Both technologies are not mutual exclusive.

If you don't like the idea of mixing different technologies: Stick to a solid OOP design and separate concerns between domain logic and data access cleanly, then switching to an ORM shouldn't be that painful or at least possible.

Good luck!